# Xamarin Forms - Reference XAML from Android specific .cs file

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a page called `MapPage.xaml` and a code behind called `MapPage.xaml.cs`. In my android project, I have another file called `CustomMapRenderer.cs`. In the `CustomMapRenderer.cs` file, I need to retrieve the item selected variable in a XAML picker found in my `MapPage.xaml` file, which changes when a user picks an option in my XAML picker.

How to I reference the picker from my `CustomMapRenderer.cs`?

Comment: You have to use a Custom Renderer for your picker.

Comment: Why is that @BrunoCaceiro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the CustomMapRenderer.cs file, I need to retrieve the item selected variable in a XAML picker found in my MapPage.xaml file, which changes when a user picks an option in my XAML picker.

If you followed the official doc [Customizing a Map](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/) to create your `CustomMapRenderer`, then in PCL, there should be a class which inherits from `Map`, for example:

```cs
public class CustomMap : Map
{

}
```

Then, if your picker is another control in your `MainPage`, you can create a bindable property for your `CustomMap`, and override `OnElementPropertyChanged` in your renderer to get this property when it changed.

For example, in PCL:

```cs
public class MapWithMyZoomControl : Map
{
    public ZoomState MyZoom
    {
        get { return (ZoomState)GetValue(MyZoomProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyZoomProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty MyZoomProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            propertyName: "MyZoom",
            returnType: typeof(ZoomState),
            declaringType: typeof(MapWithMyZoomControl),
            defaultValue: ZoomState.normal,
            propertyChanged: OnZoomPropertyChanged);

    public static void OnZoomPropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
    }

    public enum ZoomState
    {
        normal,
        zoomin,
        zoomout
    }
}
```

And in its renderer:

```cs
public class MapWithMyZoomControlRenderer : MapRenderer, IOnMapReadyCallback
{
    private GoogleMap map;

    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        map = googleMap;

        map.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            // Unsubscribe
        }

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            var formsMap = (MapWithMyZoomControl)e.NewElement;

            ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        var element = Element as MapWithMyZoomControl;
        if (e.PropertyName == "MyZoom" && map != null)
        {
            if (element.MyZoom == MapWithMyZoomControl.ZoomState.zoomin)
            {
                map.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.ZoomIn());
            }
            else if (element.MyZoom == MapWithMyZoomControl.ZoomState.zoomout)
            {
                map.AnimateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.ZoomOut());
            }
            element.MyZoom = MapWithMyZoomControl.ZoomState.normal;
        }
    }
}
```

Out of this map control, I use buttons to control to zoom the map:

```cs
map.MyZoom = MapWithMyZoomControl.ZoomState.zoomin;
```

It'a a demo, but you can modify it to make property connected to your picker.

Comment: Thanks for this in-depth answer Grace, I am going through it now